# Same scale on the axes but different lengths of the axes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a plot for a piecewise function. The domain is from `-2` to `2` and the range is from `-8` to `8`. I specify `width=2.5in` and `height=2.5in` and `axis equal`. Shouldn't these specifications give me the same scaling along the axes. ("If every `x` centimeters rightward on the plot corresponds to a change of `1`, every `x` centimeters upward on the plot corresponds to a change of `1`.") Why is the `x`-axis drawn from `-8` to `8`?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=2.5in, height=2.5in, axis equal, axis on top, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2,xmax=2, domain=-2:2,
    ymin=-8,ymax=8,
    restrict y to domain=-8:8,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x},ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-7.5pt, shorten <=-7.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=7.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=7.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=501, domain=-2:0] {-x^3};
\addplot[samples=2, domain=0:1] {x + 1};
\addplot[samples=2, domain=1:2] {-7} node[anchor=west, pos=1, font=\scriptsize]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$y=f(x)$}};

\coordinate (P) at (0,0);
\coordinate (Q) at (0,1);
\coordinate (R) at (1,-7);

\end{axis}

\draw[fill=white] (P) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill=white] (R) circle (1.5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, `axis equal` guarantees that both axes will be scaled the same, but it has the often undesirable effect of enlarging their limits as well (section 4.10 of [pgfplots' documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)).

If instead you want `x` to go from `-2` to `2`, then `axis equal image` is the way to go. This option will make the units the same but will keep the variables inside the values that you specify.

Here's what the code would look like:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=2.5in,
        axis equal image, 
        axis on top, 
        clip=false,
        axis lines=middle,
        xmin=-2,
        xmax=2, 
        domain=-2:2,
        ymin=-8,
        ymax=8,
        restrict y to domain=-8:8,
        xtick={\empty},
        ytick={\empty},
        axis line style={latex-latex},
        xlabel=\textit{x},
        ylabel=\textit{y},
        axis line style={
            shorten >=-7.5pt, 
            shorten <=-7.5pt
        },
        xlabel style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, 
            xshift=7.5pt, 
            anchor=north west
        },
        ylabel style={
            at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},
            yshift=7.5pt, 
            anchor=south west
        }
    ]

        \addplot[samples=501, domain=-2:0] {-x^3};
        \addplot[samples=2, domain=0:1] {x + 1};
        \addplot[samples=2, domain=1:2] {-7} node[anchor=west, pos=1, font=\scriptsize]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$y=f(x)$}};

        \coordinate (P) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (Q) at (0,1);
        \coordinate (R) at (1,-7);

    \end{axis}

    \draw[fill=white] (P) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[fill] (Q) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[fill=white] (R) circle (1.5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here's the resulting plot:

[image]

Note that we can get rid of either the `height` or the `width` specification. Once we have set, say, the `height` in inches, the `width` will be immediately restricted, so that `x` goes from `-2` to `2` with the same step as the vertical axis.

Comment: That does answer the question in my post. Thanks.

Comment: Now that I look at it, the plot would look better if the horizontal scaling was twice that of the vertical spacing. The line segment between `(0,1)` and `(1,2)` and the horizontal line segment are too short. May you help me with this modification? I seem to remember the option "`unit vector ratio`".

Comment: My pleasure. And yes, that's one way to do it. You could try something like `unit vector ratio=2 1`; this will make the `x` units twice as large as the units of `y`. An alternative would be to set the `width` manually and abandon the `axis equal image` altogether. This playing around, by the way, is how it goes with `pgfplots` most of the time. In my experience, the process becomes easier if you enclose your tikzpicture inside an \fbox {...}.